# How to schedule a SSIS package job in SQL sheduler or Windows scheduler?

Tags: ssis

I have created a (SSIS) package which contains SQL procedures for transfer of data from tables. It is in .dtsx format as per SSIS package. Now how to add this to a schedular so that it runs automatically after every 3 months. I am unable to get any information through google.

The windows also has a scheduler but it runs only .exe files through scheduler. Can I convert between .dtsx to .exe?

Also how to add this to the SQl server scheduler? Please help. Any link will be useful also.

Comment: If you can deploy package on SQL server then you can schedule it thru SQL job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run your SSIS package using `dtexec` command like from dos command prompt

```
dtexec /f %PackagePath%\%PackageName% /conf %PackagePath%\%ConfigName%
```

you just add this command to a batch file (.bat) and have that scheduled in your scheduler.

Check this link on DTEXEC utility

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

An other solution is to schedule the packages through SQL Server agent and creating a job so that you can scedule it once in 3 months.

Answer (score 2):

You may also schedule your SSIS package using the following files:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f   
"D:\Package.dtsx"
```