# SSIS Schedule a package without Using SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to automate the SSIS Package but i do not want to use SQL Server Agent. IS there any ways I can Schedule a job without SQL server Agent?

Thanks,
Harsh

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079616/how-to-schedule-a-ssis-package-job-in-sql-sheduler-or-windows-scheduler

Comment: Please do a search before you try you will get plenty option and learn much.

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file to run package and schedule using task scheduler.

```
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7
```